# Free/Libre geography game for learning where something is located on a map

Tags: open-source, game, maps, educational, geography

I’m looking for a geography game that can help learning where cities/countries/rivers/seas/etc. are located on maps.

Ideally the game would have this workflow (but it’s not necessary to be exactly like this):

- The game asks a **question**.
- Every question involves a **map**.

  Depending on the task/question, the map might show different levels of details (political borders, mountains, body of waters, etc.) and focus/zoom on specific parts (e.g., whole world, single continent, single country).
- The player tries to answer the question by **pointing at a location on the map** or **typing** in the answer.
- The game gives **feedback** (if correct or not, and what the correct answer/location would be).
- The game tracks the player’s **progress** and repeats problematic questions.

Example questions:

- *Which country is this?* (showing a continent where one country is highlighted, and the player has to enter its name)
- *Where is Amsterdam?* (showing the Netherlands, or even Europe without any policital borders, and the player has to place a pin on the map)
- *Where is Estonia?* (showing the whole world with policital borders, and the player has to select one of the countries)

The operating system doesn’t matter (can be for desktop, for mobile, or a Web app), but it must be **FLOSS** (including the maps!).

Comment: Why must it be open-source?

Comment: @unforgettableid: Because I only install software if it’s Free/Libre (and in case of a Web app, I don’t want to rely on someone else hosting it).

Comment: Why not use closed-source software which is given away at no charge?

Comment: @unforgettableid: Again, because I don’t install proprietary software. This is not about price (I also pay for some Free/Libre software), but freedom. -- If you have a good recommendation for a proprietary game, you could create a separate question with a self-answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [website with online geography games](http://www.sheppardsoftware.com/Geography.htm).

It might not be exactly what you were looking for, but I think it's worth giving it a try.

You can select a specific region, within which you can learn capitals, countries, landscapes, etc. For each task there is a tutorial phase, where you basically click on an object on the map and a computer voice tells you what it is. Then there are 'games' where you have to find objects on the map.

Answer (score 0):

I sounds like you are looking for [Settra](http://www.seterra.net/) from [Marianne Wartoft](http://www.wartoft.nu/software/about-me.aspx)

- Free (No Adverts, etc), and freely distributable *but not sure if it has been Open Sourced*.
- Translated to 19 languages
- Online version available [here](http://online.seterra.net/en/).
- Covers more than just North America
- Countries, states, flags, cities and capitals all over the world!
- Also include things like lakes, etc.
- Runs on most versions of Windows and I am told will run in Wine on Linux or Parallels on Mac.
- Various levels of detail.

### Examples from the web version

[image: Screenshot from Online Version]
[image: UK Cities]